# Trouble getting started with JSON + Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm new to JSON and read a few tutorials, looked in the API and searched for related posts. I already added the javax.json-1.0.4 JAR to my project (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4). I need to retrieve some information out of JSON files that I will use in an algorithm. An excerpt of a sample JSON file:

```
"topology": "sndlib_raw:/sndlib_atlanta", 
"server_kind": "uniform", 
"success": 1, 
"algorithm": "BachelorthesisCR", 
"spread_factor": Infinity, 
"r_client": "{0: 12, 1: 1, 2: 0}", 
"tried_scalings": NaN, 
"service_rate": NaN, 
"jobid": "00a77fbd-1167-4843-bd3e-7754125fc173", 
"templateshort": "Video", 
"graph": {
    "nodes": {
        "0": {
            "geolocation": [
                -0.20689655172414234, 
                -2.3478260869565304
            ], 
            "name": "N1", 
            "kcost": 0.0, 
            "k": 6, 
            "plot_coord": [
                177.65217391304347, 
                89.793103448275858
            ], 
            "ar": 0, 
            "sr": 1.0, 
            "users": 0
        }, 
        "1": {
            "geolocation": [
                -19.655172413793096, 
                129.13043478260869
```

...

```
"edges": {
        "0,7": {
            "lat": 0.0, 
            "dr": 30.0, 
            "geodistance": 8882.5879243898
        }, 
        "0,6": {
            "lat": 0.0, 
            "dr": 30.0, 
            "geodistance": 8756.266243327267
        },
```

Most of the information in the file is irrelevant for me. I am only interested in "r_client", the nodes and some of their information and a few more things. Hence, I thought it might be easier using the JSON Object Model API rather than the Streaming API.

In a test program I wanted to read and print the node names:

```
public JSONReader (String input) throws FileNotFoundException {
    inputFile = input;
    reader = Json.createReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    jsonst = reader.read(); 
}

public void read () {
    JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();
    JsonArray results = obj.getJsonArray("nodes");
    int i = 0;
    String nodeName = "" + i;
    for (JsonObject result : results.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class)) {
        System.out.println(result.getJsonObject(nodeName).getString("name"));
        i++;
        nodeName = "" + i;
    }
}
```

However, I am unsure when to use JsonObject and when JsonArray. If I should rather use JsonReader or JsonParser? I don't need to change the JSON file.
When I start the program I get a "JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 78". According to existing posts this is because of unquoted stuff like "tried_scalings": NaN where NaN is not quoted. I tried JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES; as suggested somewhere, but it didn't work. Or is that only possible for Jackson (what's the difference?)?

How can I travers all the nodes of the "edge"-subtree without knowing their names?

Comment: Before you go any further, go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then know that JSON is independent of the particular form that different languages use to represent its structures.  In Java you can use Maps (to represent JSON "objects") and Lists (for JSON "arrays"), but the rules for "generics" (if you use them at all) make using Maps/Lists a PITA, so other JSON-specific class libraries are used instead.  **DO NOT** get confused into believing that JSON must always map to "POJOs" -- that's sometimes convenient, but also very confusing for the newbie.

Comment: Your above JSON listing is missing the initial `{` character, a classical mistake for someone who does not understand the syntax.  `{}` denotes an *object* and `[]` denotes an *array*.  (Go to json.org and learn the rest.)

Comment: @HotLicks the example json is an excerpt, i dont think the 'missing' {} or [] are an issue

Comment: @TimCastelijns - They are if you don't know they're missing.

Comment: There are at least a dozen different JSON kits for Java, and several use the same set of class names.  So you need to specify which kit you're using when you ask a question here.

Comment: (And from what I've seen the javax.json kit is one of the worst and probably should be avoided.)

Comment: { isn't missing in the original file, I just didn't copy all of it. Your tip with the syntax was helpful, it's really easy to learn. But I'm still confused about the best way to process it in Java.
I added the URL to where I got the JSON kit from. The kit is working fine so far.

Comment: It's Oracle's [javax.json package](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) that sucks.  Dunno about the glassfish one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not a valid JSON - Infinity and NaN are not keywords in JSON (it's not JavaScript). Go pass it through a decent linter, e.g. use http://jsonlint.com

If you want laxer handling (and really fast) go for jackson.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Java:

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper (); // can reuse, share globally
  mapper.configure (Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true);
  JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree (new File ("foo.json"));
  // assuming "edges" is a property of the root object
  final JsonNode edges = tree.get ("edges");
  for (JsonNode edge : edges)
  {
    final double lat = edge.get ("lat").asDouble ();
    final double dr = edge.get ("dr").asDouble ();
    final double geodistance = edge.get ("geodistance").asDouble ();
  }
}
```

As for your later question for how to traverse a `JsonNode` - come on, it's all in the [JavaDoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html). A `JsonNode` implements `Iterable<JsonNode>` which is as simple as it can get when it comes for iterating...

Comment: Is there any option to just ignore those non-keywords? Or existing algorithms that fix missing quotations or just delete the relevant lines? I have several thousand of those json-files (they're test instances), so that would be handy. What about that ".Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES;" thing?

Comment: Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES is for field names, not field values. You can make the JSON parser less strict and allow {foo:"bar"} structures instead of {"foo":"bar"}.

Comment: Added an example how to use a jackson with Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS - that's probably what you need. See https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.Feature.html for a full list of available features.

Comment: I tried using Jackson, but it seems I need to configure something. So far I just added the jackson-databind-2.4.3.jar (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.3/) to my project, imported com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.* and copied your code. But I get multiple markers at the line with mapper.readTree(new File("foo.json")). Type ...JsonParser, JsonProcessingException, TreeNode cannot be resolved. Indirectly referenced from required class file...
Do I need another JAR? Should I have kept the JSON JAR alongside the Jackson JAR?

Comment: You need both jars - jackson-core and jackson-databind. You can drop the other json jar.

Comment: Turns out I need the third jar jackson-annotations as well.

Comment: You shouldn't need that - my test program run fine without that. It's only needed if you want to use jackson's annotation. Of course I refer to 2.4.3.

Comment: I didn't work for me without it. 
One more thing: How can I access every node of one subtree sequentially? In my case the topology includes a graph with nodes and link and I want to access all the link of the subtree "Links", but I don't know the keywords for the link a priori. Is there something like getNextNode?
I read the Jackson tutorial (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/), but it left this question unanswered.